# Controlling a camera from Qt: interaction of OS threads with the event loop

Tags: multithreading, qt, camera, sleep

I'm working on a Qt application to control an industrial camera, and in particular I need to trigger the camera at a particular time (when various illumination settings have been put in place, for example), and wait until a frame is returned. In the simplest case, the following code does the job nicely:

```
void AcquireFrame()
{
    // Runs in the main GUI thread:
    camera -> m_mutex.lock();
    camera -> frameHasArrived = false;
    camera -> m_mutex.unlock();
    camera -> triggerImageAcquisition();

    forever
    {
        camera -> m_mutex.lock()
        bool isReady = camera -> frameHasArrived;
        camera -> m_mutex.unlock()
        if (isReady)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Sleep(10);
        }
    }
}

void callback(camera *)
{
    // Called by the camera driver from a separate OS thread - not a Qt thread - 
    // when a frame is ready:
    camera -> m_mutex.lock();
    camera -> frameHasArrived = true;
    camera -> m_mutex.unlock();
}
```

...and most of the time this works perfectly well. However, this being the real world, occasionally the camera will fail to receive the trigger or the computer will fail to receive the frame cleanly, and the above code will then go into an infinite loop.

The obvious thing to do is to put in a timeout, so if the frame is not received within a certain time then the image acquisition can be attempted again. The revised code looks like:

```
void AcquireFrame()
{
    camera -> m_mutex.lock();
    camera -> frameHasArrived = false;
    camera -> m_mutex.unlock();
    camera -> triggerImageAcquisition();

    QTime timeout;
    timeout.start();
    forever
    {
        timeout.restart();

fetch:  camera -> m_mutex.lock()
        bool isReady = camera -> frameHasArrived;
        camera -> m_mutex.unlock()
        if (isReady)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (timeout.elapsed() > CAM_TIMEOUT) 
        { 
            // Assume the first trigger failed, so try again:
            camera -> triggerImageAcquisition();
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            Sleep(10);
            goto fetch;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that with this latter version the failure rate (the proportion of 'unsuccessful triggers') is much, much higher - at least an order of magnitude. Moreover, this code too will eventually find itself in an infinite loop where, however many times it tries to re-trigger the camera, it never sees a frame come back. Under these latter circumstances, killing the application and checking the camera reveals that the camera is in perfect working order and patiently waiting for its next trigger, so it doesn't appear to be a camera problem. I'm coming to the conclusion that in fact it's some sort of a system resource issue or a thread conflict, so that Qt's event loop is not allowing the camera callback to be called at the proper time.

Is this likely, and is there in fact a better way of doing this?

---

Update on 6th June:

For what it's worth, I've seen no more problems since I adopted the method below (having given the camera object an extra member, namely a QWaitCondition called 'm_condition'):

```
void AcquireFrame()
{
    bool frameReceived;

    forever
    {
        camera -> triggerImageAcquisition();

        camera -> m_mutex.lock();
        frameReceived = camera -> m_condition.wait(&camera->m_mutex, CAM_TIMEOUT);

        if (frameReceived)
        {
            // We received a frame from the camera, so can return:
            camera -> m_mutex.unlock();
            return;
        }

        // If we got to here, then the wait condition must have timed out. We need to
        // unlock the mutex, go back to the beginning of the 'forever' loop and try 
        // again:
        camera -> m_mutex.unlock();
    }
}

void callback (camera *)
{
    // Called by the camera driver from a separate OS thread -
    // not a QThread - when a frame is ready:
    camera -> m_condition.wakeOne();
}
```

This still has the effect of pausing the main thread until we have either received a frame or experienced a timeout, but now we have eliminated the Sleep() and the Qt event loop remains in full control throughout. It's still not clear to me why the old method caused so many problems - I still suspect some sort of system resource limitation - but this new approach seems to be more lightweight and certainly works better.

Comment: OMG, did I see a `goto`?

Comment: Don't knock them; when you're only jumping a short distance and their function is clear, they can make for much more compact code.

Comment: Well, in this case goto doesn't make things clearer. You could just remove `goto fetch;` and `continue;` and move `timeout.restart();` where `continue;` currently is.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right. Touche.

Comment: The Qt event loop doesn't remain in full control. When you wait on a wait condition, the event loop doesn't spin.

Answer (score 1):

Running the `AcquireFrame` that blocks on mutexes in the GUI thread makes not much sense to me unless you wanted to trade off GUI reponsiveness for latency, but I doubt that you care about the latency here as the camera snaps single frames and you insist on processing them in the busy GUI thread in the first place.

Secondly, there is nothing that Qt would do to prevent the callback from getting called from the other thread, other than the other thread having lower priority and being preempted by higher priority threads completely monopolizing the CPU.

I would simply post an event to a QObject in the GUI thread (or any other QThread!) from the callback function. You can post events from any thread, it doesn't matter -- what matters is the receiver. `QCoreApplication::postEvent` is a static function, after all, and it doesn't check the current thread at all.

In a complex application you probably want to have the logic in a dedicated controller QObject, and not spread across QWidget-derived classes. So you'd simply post the event to the controller instance.

Do note that posting an event to an idle GUI thread will work exactly the same as using a mutex -- Qt's event loop uses a mutex and sleeps on that mutex and on messages from the OS. The beautiful thing is that Qt already does all the waiting for you, but the wait is interruptible. The posted event should have a high priority, so that it'll end up the first one in the queue and preempt all the other events. When you're ready to acquire the frame, but before you trigger it, you can probably call `QCoreApplication::flush()`. That's about it.

There should be no problem in having a separate image processor QObject living in a dedicated QThread to leverage multicore machines. You can then process the image into a QImage, and forward that one to the GUI thread using another event, or simply via a signal-slot connection. You can probably also notify the GUI thread when you've acquired the frame but are only beginning to process it. That way it'd be more obvious to the user that something is happening. If image processing takes long, you can even send periodic updates that'd be mapped to a progress bar.

The benchmark results (using release builds) are interesting but in line with the fact that Qt's event queues are internally protected by a mutex, and the event loop waits on that mutex. Oh, the results seem to be portable among mac and windows xp platforms.

Using a naked wait condition is *not* the fastest way, but using a naked posted event is even *slower*. The fastest way is to use a queued signal-slot connection. In that case, the cost of posting an event to the same thread (that's what the `FrameProcessorEvents::tick()` does) seems to be negligible.

#### Mac

```
warming caches...
benchmarking...
wait condition latency: avg=45us, max=152us, min=8us, n=1001
queued signal connection latency: avg=25us, max=82us, min=10us, n=1000
queued event latency: avg=71us, max=205us, min=14us, n=1000
```

#### Windows XP under VMWare Fusion

Note that results over 1ms are likely due to VMWare being not scheduled at the moment.

```
warming caches...
benchmarking...
wait condition latency: avg=93us, max=783us, min=8us, n=1000
queued signal connection latency: avg=46us, max=1799us, min=0us, n=1000
queued event latency: avg=117us, max=989us, min=18us, n=1001
```

Below is the benchmarking code.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits>
#include <QtCore>

QTextStream out(stdout);

class TimedBase : public QObject
{
public:
    TimedBase(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) { reset(); }
    friend QTextStream & operator<<(QTextStream & str, const TimedBase & tb) {
        return str << "avg=" << tb.avg() << "us, max=" << tb.usMax << "us, min="
                   << tb.usMin << "us, n=" << tb.n;
    }
    void reset() { usMax = 0; n = 0; usMin = std::numeric_limits<quint32>::max(); usSum = 0; }
protected:
    quint64 n, usMax, usMin, usSum;
    quint64 avg() const { return (n) ? usSum/n : 0; }
    void tock() {
        const quint64 t = elapsed.nsecsElapsed() / 1000;
        usSum += t;
        if (t > usMax) usMax = t;
        if (t < usMin) usMin = t;
        n ++;
    }
    QElapsedTimer elapsed;
};

class FrameProcessorEvents : public TimedBase
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FrameProcessorEvents(QObject * parent = 0) : TimedBase(parent) {}
public slots: // can be invoked either from object thread or from the caller thread
    void tick() {
        elapsed.start();
        QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new QEvent(QEvent::User), 1000);
    }
protected:
    void customEvent(QEvent * ev) { if (ev->type() == QEvent::User) tock(); }
};

class FrameProcessorWait : public TimedBase
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FrameProcessorWait(QObject * parent = 0) : TimedBase(parent) {}
    void start() {
        QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(spinner()));
    }
public: // not a slot since it must be always invoked in the caller thread
    void tick() { elapsed.start(); wc.wakeAll(); }
protected:
    QMutex mutex;
    QWaitCondition wc;
protected slots:
    void spinner() {
        forever {
            QMutexLocker lock(&mutex);
            if (wc.wait(&mutex, 1000)) {
                tock();
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
};

FrameProcessorEvents * fpe;
FrameProcessorWait * fpw;

static const int avgCount = 1000;
static const int period = 5;

class FrameSender : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FrameSender(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent), n(0), N(1) {
        QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(start()));
    }
protected slots:
    void start() {
        out << (N ? "warming caches..." : "benchmarking...") << endl;
        // fire off a bunch of wait ticks
        n = avgCount;
        timer.disconnect();
        connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(waitTick()));
        fpw->reset();
        fpw->start();
        timer.start(period);
    }
    void waitTick() {
        fpw->tick();
        if (!n--) {
            if (!N) { out << "wait condition latency: " << *fpw << endl; }
            // fire off a bunch of signal+event ticks
            n = avgCount;
            fpe->reset();
            timer.disconnect();
            connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), fpe, SLOT(tick()));
            connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(signalTick()));
        }
    }
    void signalTick() {
        if (!n--) {
            if (!N) { out << "queued signal connection latency: " << *fpe << endl; }
            // fire off a bunch of event-only ticks
            n = avgCount;
            fpe->reset();
            timer.disconnect();
            connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(eventTick()));
        }
    }
    void eventTick() {
        fpe->tick();
        if (!n--) {
            if (!N) { out << "queued event latency: " << *fpe << endl; }
            if (!N--) {
                qApp->exit();
            } else {
                start();
            }
        }
    }

protected:
    QTimer timer;
    int n, N;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QThread eThread;
    QThread wThread;
    eThread.start(QThread::TimeCriticalPriority);
    wThread.start(QThread::TimeCriticalPriority);
    fpw = new FrameProcessorWait();
    fpe = new FrameProcessorEvents();
    fpw->moveToThread(&eThread);
    fpe->moveToThread(&wThread);
    FrameSender s;
    a.exec();
    eThread.exit();
    wThread.exit();
    eThread.wait();
    wThread.wait();
    return 0;
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but in this case latency really is the issue: it's an embedded application where the GUI (such as it is) is non-interactive and exists only for displaying the current status of what's going on. At the point in the code where my example comes from, the main thread really has nothing to do except spin its wheels waiting for the frame to arrive, but needs to get going with it a.s.a.p. once the frame arrives. The overriding consideration is not, under any circumstances, to risk missing the frame when it comes. See my edit, above...

Comment: Since internally Qt's even queues use mutexes just like you do, there's no real latency difference. Put the worker-upon-a-frame QObject to a separate realtime priority thread and that should do it. That QObject won't be receiving many other events and will stay ready for the event from the callback function. You can post an empty QEvent of a custom type, that's all. The nicety of this approach is that you can trivially stop the receiver thread, and there's no possibility of it getting stuck.

Comment: And the benchmarks show that I'm right. There's no benefit to using a naked QMutex because that's what Qt does anyway. You'd think you decrease the cache pressure slightly by using a naked mutex since there's no Qt code executed between the wakeup and return of control to your code. Alas, the benchmarks show that this difference is immaterial and other factors take over.

Comment: If you want to squeeze out the last bit of performance, use `QElapsedTimer` to take latency measurements in your production code, and compare posting a QEvent vs. using a signal-slot connection (queued, it's across threads) vs. using a wait condition. I bet that in busy production code the differences will be just as immaterial.

Comment: Thank you again for your full response on this question; you make the case very compellingly. Since my application is now performing well with the QWaitCondition solution, I think I'm going to leave it alone for now but I'll refer back to this when I do the next refactor, probably within the next month or two.

Answer (score 0):

How much work is it to detect the trigger state and fire the camera?
If that's relatively cheap - I would have a separate thread just blocking on a trigger event and firing the camera. Then have the main thread informed by a Qt signal sent from the callback function.

Comment: It doesn't seem like much work at all - the processor and memory utilization while all this is going on are pretty low. There are a lot of other QThreads and signals buzzing around at the same time though (servicing RS232 and TCP/IP lines), and I've found in the past that having too many of these can lead to lockups. Hence I'm looking for the solution with the lowest latency, under the constraint that the camera driver is running an OS thread and not a QThread.